# Three.js skybox rendering as red cube then disappearing?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm using Three.js and trying to put in a skybox with my own shader. I can't seem to find the issue on my own and I'm not getting any console warnings or errors.

I made the skybox small to see if it was even loading, when the page loads it flashes up red then disappears, if I enlarge the skybox it's all just white.

My js:

```
// Cubemap
var deception_pass = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
  .setPath( 'img/deception_pass/' )
  .load( [
  'deception_pass_ft.png', 'deception_pass_bk.png',
  'deception_pass_up.png', 'deception_pass_dn.png',
  'deception_pass_rt.png', 'deception_pass_lf.png'
  ] );

var cubemap = { type: 't', value: deception_pass }

// Skybox
var skyboxUniforms = {
  cubemap : cubemap,
};

var skyboxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: skyboxUniforms,
});

var loader = new THREE.FileLoader();
   loader.load('glsl/skybox.vs.glsl', function(shader) {
     skyboxMaterial.vertexShader = shader
   });
   loader.load('glsl/skybox.fs.glsl', function(shader) {
     skyboxMaterial.fragmentShader = shader
   });

var skyboxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(skyboxGeometry, skyboxMaterial);
scene.add(skybox)
```

Vertex shader:

```
uniform samplerCube cubemap;
varying vec3 worldPos;

    void main() {

    worldPos = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));

    // Move position with camera
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * vec4(position + cameraPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform samplerCube cubemap;
varying vec3 worldPos;

void main() {

    vec4 color = textureCube(cubemap, worldPos);

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Found my mistake - I was missing the material side property for my skybox. The below fixed it

```
var skyboxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        skybox: { type: "t", value: cubemap },
    },
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
})
```